# Группировка вершин в социальном графе

Tags: алгоритм, графы, визуализация

Есть желание написать библиотеку для отрисовки социального графа (я знаю что такие есть), но не совсем представляю себе как компоновать вершины (людей) в группы как тут:

[image: http://beta.hstor.org/storage1/f64c9ca5/64f45a30/91769a34/bf231d78.jpg]

В процессе гугления нашел много теории по социальным графам, для чего они нужны и т.д., но нигде толком нет алгоритмов группировки вершин.
Буду благодарен если кто-то поделится соображениями, знаниями и ссылками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема компонования людей в группы известна как community extraction. Классические алгоритмы используемые для этого это K-means, latent space models, stochastic block models, spectral clustering (не знаю как все эти вещи называются по-русски). Более новые идеи состоят в различных способах структурного приближения. Примеры статей на интересующую вас тему:

- I.S. Dhillon, S. Mallela, and D.S. Modha. Information-theoretic co-clustering. In Proceedings of the 9th ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining, pages 89–98, 2003.
- M. S. Handcock, A. E. Raftery, and J. M. Tantrum. Model-based clustering for social networks. Journal of The Royal Statistical Society Seies A, 127(2):301–354, 2007.
- M.E.J. Newman. Fast algorithm for detecting community structure in networks. Physical Review E, 69(6):066113, 2004.
- Jie Cao, Zhiang Wu, and Junjie Wu*. Community Extraction from Massive Social Networks. in SIGBPS Workshop on Business Processes and Services (BPS’12)